# Database design advantages for using one-to-many vs many-to-many relationships

Tags: sql, database, foreign-keys, schema

I'm trying to design a new database structure and was wondering of any advantages/disadvantages of using one-to-many vs many-to-many relationships between tables for the following example.

Let's say we need to store information about clients, products, and their addresses (each client and product may have numerous different addresses (such as "shipping" and "billing")).

One way of achieving this is:
[image: One-to-many relationships]

This is a rather straight forward approach where each relationship is of one-to-many type, but involves creating additional tables for each address type.

On the other hand we can create something like this:
[image: Many-to-many relationships]

This time we simply store an additional "type" field indicating what kind of address it is (Client-Billing (0), Client-Shipping (1), Product-Contact (2)) and "source_id" which is either (Clients.ID or Products.ID depending on the "type" field's value).

This way "Addresses" table doesn't have a "direct" link to any other tables, but the structure seems to be a lot simpler.

My question is if either of those approaches have any significant advantages or is it just a matter of preference? Which one would you choose? Are there any challenges I should be aware of in the future while extending the database? Are there any significant performance differences?

Thank you.

Comment: Of the two, I like the first one because it is more normalized.  Challenges in the future include handling address changes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that you have pretty much covered the answer yourself.
To me it really depends on what you are modelling and how you think it will change in the future.
Personally I'd not recommend over engineering solutions, so the one-to-many solution sound great.
However if you expect that your needs will change in say 1 month then select the many-to-many.
It's really what you need.
You could change the database at a later stage to have a many-to-many relationship but will have a cost & time impact.
Personally I'd keep the database structure as simple as needed, however understanding how you'd change it later.
Personally I only used MS-SQL Server, so perhaps others have a better understanding of other database technologies.
I think it'd be interesting to see what you are using to access your database, eg Sprocs, or something like NHibernate or Entity Framework.
If you believe that the changing the database structure could cause you big issues (it always has for me), experiment and find out how you'd do it.
That'll give you the experience you need to make more informed decisions.

Answer (score 1):

There seems to be redundancy in both of the designs, using junction tables with an "address type" field with a unique constraint accross all three columns would minimize this.

- client          : `id | name`
- client_address  : `client_id | address_id | address_type`
- address         : `id | line_one | line_two | line_three | line_four | line_five`
- product_address : `product_id | address_id | address_type`
- product         : `id | name`

either that or make the address type an attribute of product and client

- client  : `id | name | billing_address | contact_address`
- address : `id | line_one | line_two | line_three | line_four | line_five`
- product : `id | name | billing_address | contact_address`

Comment: Thanks for your input. The first approach looks very promising. I'll think about it.
However your second approach wouldn't suit me since in my case one client may have many contact_addresses.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with the bottom model is that you will end up storing redundant data when the billing and shipping addresses are the same.

You could keep your associated table from the bottom model but remove the actual address fields from that and put them in their own table, that way you're not storing addresses multiple times, still normalized, but with 2 fewer tables.